# How to view local drawing DWF file with correct font?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I am trying to view local dwf files in browser using forge viewer.

I followed this: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/dwf-and-pdf-support-forge-viewer
example to load local dwf file into the viewer.

```
let option = { env: "Local" };
        
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(option, async function () {

            const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'));
            viewer.start();
            viewer.setTheme('dark-theme');

            viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.DWF').then(() => {
                console.log("Extension Loaded")
                console.log(path);
                try {
                    viewer.loadModel(virtualPath + path);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    alert("Nepodařilo se načíst požadovaný soubor!")
                }
            });
        });
```

But there is a problem with font:
[forge-viewer-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR1Nf.png)

When I view the same file with "Autodesk Design Review" the font is correct:
[design-review-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is3PE.png)

Detailed problems I have in my implementation of Forge Viewer:

- It is not the correct ISOCPEUR and it does not support characters with diacritics.
- Also it uses blue background and looks different compared to other Autodesk viewing apps I have seen. (Vault Thin Client, DR)
- The image (company logo) is blurred

Am I missing some sort of setting to the viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're missing any settings. The native DWF loading in JavaScript is a relatively new feature, and there may be areas that require some polishing. If you wouldn't mind sharing one of the DWFs with us (confidentially via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`; the file would not be shared with anyone outside of Autodesk), we can ask the viewer engineering team to look at it.

In the meantime, have you tried converting the DWF into the viewer format using the Model Derivative service? While this operation has some cost ([0.1 flex tokens per DWF](https://aps.autodesk.com/pricing)), it uses AutoCAD to process the DWF, so it is generally more robust.

Comment: I have send you the the file. I haven't tried the model derivative API but I tried the **viewer (dot) autodesk (dot) com** And the font there is looking good and it works correctly. I presume it uses the Model Derivative service too?

Comment: Yes, it does. Is this workaround (using Model Derivative service) acceptable?